# First person sneaking wounds block view. Any way to reset model?

Tags: fallout-4

I was completing a quest at a foundry where I touched the molten steel.  I did not die, but my player model caught fire and burned for a few seconds.  I managed to save myself by taking a number of stimpaks.

Unfortunately this altered my players model seemingly permanently.  I did not notice it right away.  I have a number of permanent wounds, including most of my hip and waist region completely damaged and removed.  When I crouch in first person, most of my view is blocked with a bloody wound (presumably my face although looking at my face from the front shows no damage.

Does anyone know how I can reset my characters model?  I have tried using the console commands (sexchange, showlooksmenu) in an attempt to force a reset/redraw of the model, but the damage persists.

Comment: try `disable` followed by `enable`, dunno if it works for the player character but does for most NPCs

Comment: Just tried it.  No joy.  Damage still blocks the first person crouching view.

Comment: does the equipped armour make any difference? for instance a suit of power armour?

Comment: It did not.  Tried two different suits of power armor and two different sets of normal armor.

Answer (score 3):

The below actions result in resetting your characters looks, but it does fix the problem.  It looks like at some point I was damaged in such a way that a skeleton was added inside my model.  This apparently intersected with and was exposed from the skin on the model and when crouching, I believe I was seeing the sternum and ribcage.

To reset your characters model:

1. Enter the console `~`.
2. Select your character with the mouse.
3. `unequipall`
4. Select your character with the mouse (just to be sure).
5. `recycleactor`

Your character model should now be reset and without a skeleton, unfortunately, you will have to recreate your characters features.  Perks seem to require removal and re-add.

Use the `player.removeperk` and `player.addperk` commands to first remove perks and then re-add them otherwise they seem to display, but activate (e.g. I had Locksmith 3 perk, but could not open but the easiest locks).

Comment: This is probably the only instance in life where removing your skeleton is a good thing :P